# Laptop On-board Diagnostics at Boot Time

Tags: boot, dell-inspiron, diagnostic

I turned on my **Dell Inspiron 5555** and the on board diagnostic displayed with options to select. I cancelled that and restarted it, and everything appeared to boot fine without the on-board diagnostic options this time.

- Why does the on-board diagnostic show on PC boot?
- Is there a kind of problem that triggered it or its just a scheduled
  check up?

I ran a diagnostic check with this same tool two weeks ago and the result showed everything was just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely pressed the <kbd>F12</kbd> at computer start up when the Dell logo appeared.

> ### [Offline diagnostics](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN114988)
>
> Dell devices come with pre-boot diagnostics to diagnose hardware
>   issues and capture error codes. This set of diagnostics runs before
>   Microsoft Windows starts, so you can diagnose hardware issues without
>   a working operating system. The initial scan lasts a few minutes and
>   checks the system memory(RAM), hard disk drive, processor and several
>   other hardware components for errors.
>
> Refer to the Dell knowledge-base article [Resolve hardware issues
>   using ePSA or PSA diagnostics and guide to error
>   codes](http://www.dell.com/support/article/SLN115162/en) for more
>   information.
>
> ### **Dell Pre-boot System Assessment or enhanced Pre-boot System Assessment (PSA or ePSA)**
>
> To initialize the Dell PSA or ePSA diagnostics:
>
> 1. Restart your computer.
> 2. When the Dell logo appears, press **F12** key on the keyboard several
>      times to open the One-time Boot menu.
> 3. Use the **down arrow** key on the keyboard to select **Diagnostics** and
>      press the **Enter** key.
> 4. Follow the on-screen prompts and answer them appropriately to
>      complete the assessment.
> 5. Write down any error codes listed
> 6. Use the [Dell Interactive Support Agent (English
>      only)](https://www5.nohold.net/Dell/Loginr.aspx?pid=3&ruleid=2591&login=1)
>      to get information about ePSA or PSA diagnostic error codes.
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN114988)</sub>

Additionally, there are other key combinations or hot keys that could be pressed inadvertently which could cause the device to boot to the [Dell ePSA or PSA Diagnostics](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/266787) options.

> ### [2. Using the PSA Diagnostics](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/266787)
>
> ---
>
> **How to Enter a Notebook Computer Diagnostics**
>
> ### Notebook systems:
>
> 1. You can hold in the <kbd>**Fn**</kbd> key and the power button to boot into the diagnostics.
> 2. Alternatively you can press the <kbd>**mute**</kbd> button while powering on one of our E-series notebooks to boot to the diagnostics
>      as well.
> 3. Or you can tap the <kbd>**F12**</kbd> key at the Dell splash screen on start-up.
> 4. and choose Diagnostics from the menu.
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/266787)</sub>

Comment: nope, i just turned it on, i never pressed F12, even if i would press it will have to select the diagnostic option to actually reach the state where it starts the check up.

Comment: @IutbaZion I just updated my answer with another possibility which may boot directly into the Diagnostic mode without needing to press additional options.

Comment: thanks for your help, i guess i find the problem, i guess it is related with a boot failure but it has not happen again and my HDD is in good health maybe just a bug (i also updated my bios).